# C++: error: expected ';' before '<' token

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error with the C++ code

```
error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope"
error: expected ';' before '<' token
```

With this code:

```
struct Entry { 
    char* word; 
    char* def;
}

class Dictionary { 
    public:
    Dictionary(); 
    ~Dictionary();
    void addEntry(Entry*);
    char* getDef(const char*); 

    private:
    std::vector<Entry> dict;     //Error happens here
}
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: you forgot the semicolon. struct Entry { 
    char* word; 
    char* def;
}; and after class{};

Answer (score 7):

You forgot some semicolons:

```
struct Entry { 
    char* word; 
    char* def;
};                //C++ structs need a semicolon after the curly brace.


class Dictionary { 
    public:
    Dictionary(); 
    ~Dictionary();
    void addEntry(Entry*);
    char* getDef(const char*); 

    private:
    std::vector<Entry> dict;    

};
```

Comment: Dammit. I always forget which type of curly braces require a semi-colon afterwords.

Comment: Not with the code you posted. There has to be something else there causing the error.